# Shell script extract data from a file

Tags: mysql, shell, sed, extract

I just started programming in shell script and I have a file that looks like this:

```
stuff that doesn't matter
doesn't matter
matter

*LINE 35*School: xxxxx -> NAME: xxxxx AGE: xxx DESCRIPTION: xxxxxxxxxx
School: yyyyy -> NAME: yyyyy AGE: yyy DESCRIPTION: yyyyyyyyyy
School: zzzzz -> NAME: zzzzz AGE: zzz DESCRIPTION: zzzzzzzzzz
School: aaaaa -> NAME: aaaaa AGE: aaa DESCRIPTION: aaaaaaaaaa
6 lines of stuff after the important information
```

My main goal in this is to migrate all those students into a mysql database, my code would be something like this:

```
nstudents=(( $(wc -l file | cut -d ' ' -f1) - 41) #41 comes from 35+6
i=1
while [ $i != $nstudents ]
do
$school=[I don't know how to extract school number $i]
$name=[I don't know how to extract name number $i]
$age=[I don't know how to extract age number $i]
$desc=[I don't know how to extract description number $i]
mysql #upload
$i= (( $i + 1 ))
done
```

I know that to do this I need to use sed or something like it, but I just can't figure it out how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to try a more forgiving scripting language like Ruby or Python before diving head first into things like `bash` and its various quirky utility scripts. Shell scripting is far from ideal for interfacing with databases.

Comment: do you want to generate a set of INSERT INTO statements? can you just make a better example input (e.g. the `*LINE 35* in file or not..) and expect output?

Comment: Yes it would be a set of INSERT INTO statements.

Comment: take the time to rewrite your question with understandable input and required output. Realize that if you can provide the bare minimum of input for each type of data that you need to process AND keep the size of the record to just enough to help solve your problem, you don't need as much data as you've posted here. Also, I agree with Kent, what the heck is '*LINE 35*' ? Is that really in you data? AND what do you mean with `6 lines of stuff after the important information`? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just to point you in a shell-ish solution to your problem basd on best guess at what your data really looks like, try this

```
cat inputFile
stuff that doesn't matter
doesn't matter
matter

*LINE 35*School: xxxxx -> NAME: xxxxx AGE: xxx DESCRIPTION: xxxxxxxxxx
School: yyyyy -> NAME: yyyyy AGE: yyy DESCRIPTION: yyyyyyyyyy
School: zzzzz -> NAME: zzzzz AGE: zzz DESCRIPTION: zzzzzzzzzz
School: aaaaa -> NAME: aaaaa AGE: aaa DESCRIPTION: aaaaaaaaaa
6 lines of stuff after the important information

awk -F: '/School/{
    gsub(/ -> /, ""); sub(/School/,""); sub(/NAME/,"")
    sub(/AGE/,""); sub(/DESCRIPTION/,"")
    printf("insert into MyTable values (\"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\")\n",  $2, $3, $4, $5)     
}' inputFile
```

**output**

```
insert into MyTable values (" xxxxx", " xxxxx ", " xxx ", " xxxxxxxxxx")
insert into MyTable values (" yyyyy", " yyyyy ", " yyy ", " yyyyyyyyyy")
insert into MyTable values (" zzzzz", " zzzzz ", " zzz ", " zzzzzzzzzz")
insert into MyTable values (" aaaaa", " aaaaa ", " aaa ", " aaaaaaaaaa")
```

If you like this, look at [grymoire awk tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

IHTH